# learn python the hard way exercise 1 - file won't run in terminal

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, terminal

I have searched all around for an answer to what seems like it would be a simple question. Alas, no dice.

Problem: I cannot "run" a python file from the terminal (mac os X 10.9.2)

- running python returns:

`Python 2.7.6 (v2.7.6:3a1db0d2747e, Nov 10 2013, 00:42:54) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.`
>>>>

- attempting to run python file from terminal
- after browsing to file where 'pthw_e01.py' is created:

  $ python pthw_e01.py
  $

In summary, nothing happens when I try to run the python script (I believe it's a script not a file right?).

In case it helps you answer, the python I'm trying to run in the terminal is just a bunch of print statements (see below):

```
print "Hello World!" print "Hello Again" print "I like typing this." print "This is fun." print 'Yay! Printing.' print "I'd much rather you 'not'." print 'I "said" do not touch this.'
```

Comment: The code you've posted should throw a `SyntaxError`.  You have those print statements on separate lines, right?

Comment: What is the output you get when running `python pthw_e01.py`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have them on separate lines if they're in one big script, or input each line separately in the shell. Python normally uses new lines to figure out where it ends each statement.

**pthw_e01.py:**

```
print "Hello World!"
print "Hello Again"
print "I like typing this."
print "This is fun."
print 'Yay! Printing.'
print "I'd much rather you 'not'."
print 'I "said" do not touch this.'
```

Comment: Sorry, that was my inability to correctly use markup on StackOverflow... when running I did have them on separate lines.

Comment: I haven't gotten back to this yet.  Too much work!  I'll let you know asap.

Answer (score 0):

From your screen shot above youre trying to run a python file in the interpreter and not actually run the program in the terminal. You can run each print line in the interpreter if you choose, but not the whole file. instead of just typing python and opening the interpreter, type python pthw_e01.py and it should display your program to the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You probably saved your file when you opened it and it was empty and then didn't save your file again after you typed the text in. Check the size of your file to see if it's zero.  Save it again and rerun. You'll have to save it every time you make changes and run